# iOS App: webView or PhoneGap?

Tags: ios, iphone, html, cordova, webview

We are developing a HTML5 mobile app with Sencha Touch.

Now we want to package the App, and found that we have **two methods**:

The **first one** is to use PhoneGap to generate a native app based on our html5 code.

The **second one** is to create a Single WebView app in Xcode, and request the url which will host our HTML5 code.

I found the second method relatively easier. So are there any advantages in using PhoneGap to generate the native app?

Comment: Apple generally won't approve an app that is just a `UIWebView`; which I learned from experience.

Comment: Really? I just read this http://engineeringblog.yelp.com/2013/11/whoa-that-embedded-web-view-looks-hot-in-your-ios-app.html. It seems that Yelp is distributing their iOS app through webView.

Comment: It probably passed by an easy reviewer, but it can be pulled at any time. The guidelines state that an app that is just a collection of links or a web view will not be approved. "in laymens terms"

Comment: Looking at the article you linked to, the app appears much more complicated than just a basic standalone `UIWebView`, so if that's what you're trying to do, I'm sure it'll be approved.

Comment: phonegap have an API that lets you use native function, if you don't use any of them just use a regular webview

Answer (score 1):

We usually use phonegap/cordova when we need some native function from the device, for example a barcode scanner.

Of course you can create your own barcode project, however why reinvent the wheel. Since phonegap/cordova 3.0 the effort needed for creating a app is kinda low. Just follow the guide and your all set.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/guide_platforms_ios_index.md.html#iOS%20Platform%20Guide

in short:

Advantages of Phonegap/Cordova

- Ready for different platforms, little effort to create android app
- Native functionality already implemented (plugins)